# Failed to disabled specific page

Tags: users, 7

I'm creating an e-commerce using drupal.

In this site I have several catalogs to distinguish between some products. Let's say I have url `site_home/catalog/1` , `site_home/catalog/2`, `site_home/catalog/3`, and site_home/catalog/4`.

I need to disable view for /catalog/1 , /catalog/2 and /catalog/3, but everyone can view /catalog/4 and newly created catalog in the future which will have id > 4.

I've tried using [Pages Module](https://drupal.org/project/pages) to disable those pages.

I've created new rule with this module which is called /catalog/%catalog with arguments for %catalog is string. And then for Access Rule I added a criteria String: URL path. Current path type is not one of "catalog/1, catalog/2, catalog/3" but when i enabled this rule I got:

```
/catalog/1 - /catalog/3 --> access denied  
/catalog/4 --> page not found
```

Any ideas why this is happening, and which settings did I missed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using taxonomy terms for your catalog you could try using taxonomy term permissions https://drupal.org/project/term_permissions. If you are using a view for each catalog you can just restrict access to each view as you like.